# Sort by date in jsonb postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I have a model where the data is stored in json format in a jsonb column in postgres.

I want to sort the output by a data field using an activerecord query.

```
Model.all.order("json_data -> 'date'")
```

gives me an output but orders it alphabetically based on the date string.

Is there an easy way I can sort this as a date?

Note: The dates are in the following format:

```
"Fri, 24 Jun 2016 04:13:26 -0700"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the date is in a sensible format Postgres will deal with this automatically.

```
Model.all.order("(json_data ->> 'date')::timestamp with time zone DESC")
```

or

```
Model.all.order("(json_data ->> 'date')::timestamptz DESC")
```

If your date field string is a little unorthodox, you can do the following

```
Model.all.order("to_timestamp(json_data->>'date','Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS ') DESC")
```

Details [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html)

Note the  ->> there to output the string rather than the json object.

You can of course just create an extra column and store your information there as per @Uzbekjon's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way I can sort this as a date?

Not as part of the jsonb field, since [JSON doesn't know anything about dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10286204/52317).

---

So, an easy alternative would be to store them as a separate table column.

If you really have to store them as an element of your json field, then I would suggest one of the two options:

1. Store your field as timestamp. Since, json fields in postgresql support numeric values and it could (potentially) optimize the sorting.
2. Store your date in `ISO 8601` format string. [It would sort correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952652/52317), even if it is a string.

Comment: The issue is that I'm absorbing the data from somewhere else (it's an email stored as json) so I really don't want to have duplicated parsed fields if there's a way to keep everything clean and I can do all the parsing on the db side).

Comment: You could index the json field and convert it to a timestamp when you do, and as long as you convert the field when you order it, it will sort correctly.